# Hide Shared Site From Site Selector Options in SXA

Tags: sxa

Hopefully, a quick question. Can you hide a shared site from the 'Site Selector' component in SXA? The site is flagged as shared and has no host name but still it shows as a selection. I assume there is a check box somewhere? Maybe I missed it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, there is no option in `Sitecore` to hide a site. If you check the logic for the `Site Selector`, it is trying to get the children of the current `Tenant` like this.

```
  protected virtual IEnumerable<Item> GetSites() => (IEnumerable<Item>) this.MultisiteContext.TenantItem.Children;
```

And there is no property indicating that they are using it to mark a site as hidden.

I hope anyone has done something else to do this, but this is just my understanding.

Hope this makes sense.